# Interpreting the formula of the derivative of a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:R^2\to R $ be a differentiable function. Then we know that $$f (x+h, y+k)-f (x, y)=\frac  {\mathrm{d}f }{\mathrm{d}x }\mathrm{d}h+ \frac  {\mathrm{d}f }{\mathrm{d}y }\mathrm{d}k.$$

The way I interpret this formula is: this formula is valid only if $ \frac  {df }{dy }$ is continuous. This is because the actual formula should be $f (x+h, y+k)-f (x, y)=\frac  {df }{dx }dh+ \frac  {df }{dy }|_{x+h, y}dk  $

Is the above interpretation correct? If it is, then we have a potential problem. Because the value of $f (x+h, y+k)-f (x, y)$ is very small as h and k approach 0. And for such small values, even if $\frac  {df }{dy} $ is continuous, the error introduced by using $\frac  {df }{dy} $ instead of $\frac  {df }{dy }|_{x+h, y}$ is quite large in comparison.

Comment: The formula "we know that" is wrong as stated.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net- could you point me towards the correct formula please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused. The higher dimensional analogue of the derivative is just the gradient $\nabla f$, which always exists, so long as the components are differentiable. The "differential" that you have written $\partial_x f dx + \partial_y f dy$ is the 1-form dual to the gradient.

To get a directional derivative in the direction $u$, just take the dot product with the gradient $\nabla f \cdot u$.

Comment: What is the 1 form dual?